# What is the correct approach to waiting for a Service Fabric cluster to become available?

Tags: deployment, azure-service-fabric

I'm automating the deployment of a Service Fabric application to Azure. So far I have automated:

- The creation of the supporting infrastructure: resource group, key vault, certificate
- The deployment of the ARM template
- The build and packaging of the application itself

Now I'm at the point where I'm trying to connect to the Fabric management endpoint so I can deploy the application. However, if I attempt to connect a short time after the deployment status is "succeeded", I get a connection error. If I check the Service Fabric cluster status at the time, it is still in the process of deploying.

I could keep trying to connect every 10 seconds until I am able to hit the management endpoint, but this seems dirty, since *actual* failures to deploy the cluster would eventuate in a build timeout. However, I cannot determine the health of the cluster because the management endpoint is not yet available, so this seems like I'm stuck between a rock and a hard place.

Is there a standard, cleaner approach to determining whether my Service Fabric cluster is ready for me to connect to in order to deploy my application?

Comment: Does the following help: [Connect to a secure cluster interactively using Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-connect-to-secure-cluster#connect-to-a-secure-cluster-interactively-using-azure-active-directory)? *A dialog window automatically pops up for interactive sign-in upon connecting to the cluster.* The dialog window could be a useful indicator that the cluster is ready.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, where does this assumption come from:

```
 but this seems dirty, since actual failures to deploy the cluster would eventuate in a build timeout.
```

if arm template deployed successfully - SF cluster will come up, so there's that. second, you can use `Get-AzResource` to poll SF resource in Azure and determine its state. use exponential back off with limited number of attempts.

And this whole approach makes little sense. your application pipelines shouldn't depend on infrastructure pipelines. so your infrastructure pipeline should be marked as done as soon as the arm template deployment is finished without errors. because this timeout would happen on the first run (i'm not even sure it would, i'm just quoting you). all the subsequent arm template updates of the same cluster do not render cluster management endpoint unreachable.